# Filter gallery by current user in Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, powerapp, person-or-group

I would like to Filter the gallery by the current user in Powerapps.
It tried using `Filter('Declaraties';Naam.Email=User().Email)` in the Items field in the gallery.
But did not work.

Than I remembered. In my organisation our Microsoft mail is `firstnameuser@companyname.com`.
But it differs from our e-mail address which is `firstletterfrondnaam.lastname@companyname.com`
So I think that this formula cannot work since our email address differs from the user E-mail.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using:

```
Filter('Declaraties';Naam.DisplayName=User().FullName)
```

**Note**: Display names in your organization must be unique for every employee.